# calling rspec directly on a model results on errors in stub! method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When running:

```
rake spec:models
```

everything works well, but when I do

```
rspec spec/models/spot_spec.rb
```

that has `Spot.stub! :test1` , I get:

```
undefined method `stub!' for Spot:Class
```

The error happens only when I include that stub! line.

Any ideas how to avoid it? I want to run the specs for a specific model only.

Update:

Using Ruby 1.9.2 and RSpec 2.4.0, here is the spot_spec.rb code:

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper')

describe Spot do
  before(:all) do
    Spot.stub! :test1
    @spot = Spot.new
  end

  subject {@spot}

  describe "validations" do
    it { should validate_presence_of(:user) }
  end
end
```

And the spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
end
```

Comment: Show us the full code of `spot_spec.rb` please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Turned out to be an [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/closed#issue/279) in `before(:all)` call:

> That's correct. Mocks are implicitly
>   verified and cleared out after(:each)
>   so they won't work in before(:all).

Changing it to `before(:each)` solved it.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Have spot_spec.rb include spec_helper.rb and then make sure spec_helper.rb includes spot_spec.rb.

If you are running ruby 1.9+, you can use require_relative to include spot_spec.rb in spec_helper.rb

Update:

in spec_helper.rb add:

```
require_relative '../app/models/spot'
```

Comment: I have updated the code above, would you please point what to do exactly?